# Django Filtering

Tags: django

I'm been trying to filter usernames for a specific module.

I have this module called Person which is assoicated with User .I can grab all Person objects but how can I also grab their usernames.

My solution is to use User.objects.all() but I don't want to grab everyone like admin account . I want to only grab all the users in Person and their assoicated username.So I could use them in my function and template.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am trying my best to explain the situation 
My models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
```

My views.py

```
def Everyone(request):
    everyone = Person.objects.all()
    return render('everyone.html',{'everyone':everyone})
```

Everyone.html

```
 {% if everyone %}
     {% for one in everyone %}
     <a href ="{% url world:profile username %}">{{one.name}}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if everyone %}
     {% for one in everyone %}
     <a href ="{% url world:profile one.user.username %}">{{one.user.username}}
     {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I knew I could do this {{user.username}} but didn't know I could put {{one.user.username}} Thank you very much cathy :D

Comment: this is one of what I like in django, we can get the other field value as long as they have connection (foreignkey)

Comment: Can I ask . Person.objects.filter(user=user.id) . Does user.id refer to me?

Comment: yep, the current user login,